# One word that refers to a proof of concept for an unfinished video game?

Tags: single-word-requests

My friend and I are making a video game.  Occasionally we want to release little tech demos that demonstrate our progress.  A demo would not at all be the finished game, but would rather show off some part of the engine that we have completed.

At first we called these demos, but we are afraid that the word demo implies that they represent the finished product.  Is there a good *single* word that refers to a little mini-program that demonstrates progress but is not the finished product?

Comment: What's wrong with calling them "tech demos"?

Comment: Proof of concept is actually often used word for such a piece of software as well.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest calling them *[pilots](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pilot)*, even though that's more commonly used to denote sample episodes of a proposed TV series.  Also, as each of these technical demonstrations illustrates some new aspect or feature of your game engine, consider the word *[featurette](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/featurette)*, which refers to "a relatively short feature film".  You might also consider words like *[highlighter](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/highlight)*, *[showcase](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/showcase)*, *[exhibit](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/exhibit)*, and *[proof-of-concept](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/proof-of-concept)*.

Comment: Well highlighter and showcase seems the most suitable, the others are more appropriate for television productions. Although I remember there was such word, but I can't remember it now. It was about having several products and you are showing the best of them, that carry the concept when making presentation.

Comment: The synonyms for 'pilot' in this meaning are: prototype, alpha release, qa version, interim release, work-in-progress, partial release. 'demo' is not a synonym because a demo may not even be a working version, simply a mockup. A beta release is not because it is intended to be a full feature release (but possibly minor bugs).

Answer (score 2):

Actually, "demo" is the right word for it. According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_demo),

> A game demo is a freely distributed demonstration or preview of an upcoming or recently released video game.

[You can also use](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Video_game_development#Milestones):

- First playable
- Alpha
- Code freeze
- Beta
- Code release
- Gold master

depending upon the current stage of your game's development. And if you have to release more than one version at a particular stage, you can name them by using a combination of *numbers* and *periods (dots)*.

Comment: Alfa and Betta products refer to finished products in testing phase, something like release candidate (RC) with almost all the features already done. He is talking about showing something different to the people- Mark Zuckeberg's The Facebook without marital status.

Comment: That's why I have said, "You can also use:.... **depending upon the current stage of your game's development** "

Comment: @rudra, I haven't been to this site in a while and having returned I find that you spend a lot of time being partially (or entirely) wrong and then being really indignant and peevish in being corrected. In this particular case, you're offering an answer where it's clear you have absolutely no basis of understanding of the question.  Is there a word for such behavior? How does one describe in a single word a person who can't help but chime in with advice on matters where they have no expertise? ;)

Comment: @Dr.Dredel A guy with who has been a member since 1 year, 4 months and a reputation of 144, suddenly returns after a long time and finds out **everything** about a particular user (in this case me), and claims that he (i.e., me) always gives incorrect answers. **WEIRD** and **CREEPY**. Are you sure you are not one of those **fake accounts**?

Comment: @rudra, yeah... pretty sure I'm not a fake account.  Granted I only saw a handful of your responses, but they paint a pretty obvious picture of exactly what I describe... namely, someone that takes things personally when nothing personal was said, gets affronted easily and is tirelessly (and tiresomely) defensive. Your response to me doesn't do much to offer contrary evidence to my impression. Anyway... I'm being cheeky. You should carry on in whatever way makes you happy, obviously.

Comment: oh, and since I don't suffer from the condition I described above, I can say that I've been enjoying this site for quite some time, I just didn't have anything to add and saw no point in joining and chiming in where I wasn't needed... word to the wise... (how do you know I'm a guy?). Your score of 1777 isn't particularly impressive either, btw. (sorry) and this answer of yours is patently wrong. You misunderstood what you dug up on wikipedia, and then got all uppity when Speedy called you out on it, rather than acknowledging that you're wrong and fixing (or deleting) your answer.

Comment: You amuse me Dr.Dredel. Never did I say that my score is so great that my name should be carved in stone. All I meant was that do you think people upvote my answers because they - my answers - are always partially (or entirely) wrong, as you are saying?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3758/discussion-between-rudra-and-dr-dredel)

Comment: Having used the internet for over two weeks now, I have learned that there is no greater waste of time than "continuing" such conversations. I am quite positive that neither of us will gain anything from such a continuance. Cheers.

Comment: I understand what you are saying. But see for yourself, who started it? Look at your first comment. It's blown so much out of proportion. It shows that either you and I have a long-term enemity or you are a maniac who randomly chooses his targerts and loves to disparage them. PS- I can go on bickering about this. You see, i am free for two months. Holidays

Comment: @rudra, by all means... bicker away... Holidays are meant to be enjoyed, so, if this is what gives you pleasure, onward and upward!

Answer (score 2):

You could call it a **prototype**.  Unlike *demo*, it's clear that a prototype is meant to be thrown away and never delivered as part of the final product.  That emphasis is often necessary; otherwise project managers may get the impression that it's good enough to ship just because it looks like it works.

Answer (score 1):

That's a terrific question. Are you referring to partial builds of the entire game? Or do you mean that you're looking to show off specific in-engine features, like for instance if you develop a really good way to simulate material waving in the wind and wish to show this off?

For the former I would use "playable partial builds",  the "partial" will leave no one confused that they're not looking at anything like a finished product.

Another way to describe them is "game fragments".

If you're talking about in-engine features I would call them that. "This is an example of an in-engine feature we call "breezy cloth".  etc.

I strongly suspect you are asking about the former, though, so, while I don't think there's an official term for it, combining "playable" with "incomplete" (in one form or another) should get you to a term you like pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

When we work on a website or microsite, we use the word *mockup* for a previewable, but perhaps not fully functioning phase of the design and development process. It's at a stage where we show a client before we invest the time to finish the project. The [*mockup* entry in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockup) seems to offer the same use of the word:

> In manufacturing and design, a mockup, or mock-up, is a scale or full-size model of a design or device, used for teaching, demonstration, design evaluation, promotion, and other purposes. A mockup is a prototype if it provides at least part of the functionality of a system and enables testing of a design. Mock-ups are used by designers mainly to acquire feedback from users.